# Send binary data as application/octet-stream content type using swagger

Tags: elixir, swagger, phoenix-framework

I'm unable to send binary data as application/octet-stream content type.
Following is the information I have added to swagger_path

```
swagger_path :create do
  post "/data"
  tag "POST Data"
  summary "POST data"
  description "Send data"
  consumes "application/octet-stream"
  produces "application/octet-stream"
  parameter :Body, :binaryData, :file, "The file to upload", required: true
  response 200, "Ok"
  response 400, "Bad request"
  response 401, "Unauthorized"
end
```

When I upload a file and execute the command, I'm seeing following error

```
[info] module=Plug.Logger POST /data/
[info] module=Plug.Logger Sent 406 in 631µs
[debug] module=Plug.Debugger ** (Phoenix.NotAcceptableError) no supported media 
type in accept header.
Expected one of ["octet-stream"] but got the following formats:
* "application/octet-stream" with extensions: ["bin", "lha", "lzh", "exe",
"class", "so", "dll", "img", "iso"]
```

Here is the curl command which I would like to generate

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8000/data -H 'Content-Type: application/octet
stream'  --data-binary @conn.dat
```